# How to make VS Code recognize the tsconfig.json?

Tags: node.js, typescript

In my node.js project `.ts` file, I have

```
#date_created: Date = new Date();
```

but VSCode says

`Private identifiers are only available when targeting ECMAScript 2015 and higher.ts(18028)`

However in the root of the folder, I have this `tsconfig.json` file

```
{
    "compilerOptions": {
        "outDir": "./dist/",
        "noImplicitAny": true,
        "module": "ES6",
        "target": "ES6",
        "lib": ["ES6"],
        "allowJs": false
    }
}
```

It feels like VS Code is not reading this properly. How can I fix this?

Comment: does target:"es2016" work? Did you restart vs code after making the change?

Comment: Mmm I tried on typescript 3.9.7 and it worked fine with your config. https://repl.it/@CodyGeisler/63092132#index.ts